next js persist server side variable after Link navigation
I got a NextJS app that needs to meet a very specific scenario. Few pages of the app will be rendered inside a React Native Web View and I need to hide certain components when it is done (header and footer). The components are server side rendering simple components like below:
const Footer = () => {
  return <footer>
  <div>Lots of SEO content here, like contact, links, etc.</div>
  </footer>
}


I know I can hide those components via detecting the window.ReactNativeWebView field, but that is client side only. I added a header in my React Native app to tell the server side that it is a React Native render, which successfully hides the footer in the initial load.
The problem comes when I navigate to other sections of the site via the 'next/link' component, it causes a flickering where the footer (and header as well) shows for half a second and then goes, producing a weird flickering.
Is there a way that I can persist the server side decision of hiding a component after navigating with 'next/link'?

You can persist the server side decision using server side cookies.

thanks. I'm aware of that, but not sure why after navigation through site based on next/link links it seems the footer loose the ability to read the headers

Ah got it, Can you please share the code snippet where you are using next header in your footer to hide it.
